# Ubuntu Apps Developer Team

Tags: software-center, application-development

I'm writing on behalf of getting answers for a few questions.
I have a team and we have to develop apps for Ubuntu Software Centre.

I am the team leader and I have two members and we are growing fast,but for doing this as a team I need some guidance for getting for real involved in developing apps for Ubuntu!

1. How can we register as a team(not as a person) so we can get recognized?
2. Do we get any special tutorials for developing or I can get access to buy a book or send as one  ?
3. Do we need to register  as a "business" to our local townhall even if we want some of apps to be paid?
4. Despite we are three in total I have access to an University so we are eligible for 
   practice for students in two different cities, so we are, in fact a growing Ubuntu Community, and may be some important point in making relationships and partnership with those Universities. Is there any policy in making partnership with University through us?

Comment: 1. Dunno ; 2. Depends on previous knowledge ; 3. probably not, open-source projects might not count - unless you want to do *paid* apps ; 4. dunno again

Comment: Ok thanks,i am looking forward to answers for the others questions,I appreciate your gesture!

Comment: WFor the last question, Universities have different systems in different countries/regions, so it may help to specify where you are - and for the second, what sort of apps you are planning developing and what you have previously done may be of help. Your welcome by the way :D

Comment: WE are located in Romania, in 2 cities but central in Timisoara
and the other one is Oradea, The university is "Universitatea Politehnica Timisoara"(www.upt.ro) and "Universitatea Emanuel din Oradea"(www.emanuel.ro).
We have done just the tutorials from developer.ubuntu.com but   our main occupation is Software Developers at Alcatel-lucent (alcatel-lucent.ro)

Comment: And About what we plan to develop, We are going to hit hard where is needed ,like Organization apps (mind planning,graph statiscs,time management,and so on!and ofcourse not only ,As i said we develop where is needed!

Answer (score 0):

1. Strictly speaking I do not think you can - apps are published from a single account. There is a field for "Company name" though.
2. http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/
3. That would depend on your local regulations. In most countries, people who want to trade together as a single entity will form a legal partnership or limited company.
4. I am not aware of an Ubuntu Partner programme for academic establishments.

Comment: Group access is on the roadmap for the app store, but it's not been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks,is there any date for that feature release?